# YOLO annotation guildelines: overlapping and partially visible objects

Tags: object-detection, yolo

Can you please advise on how I should annotate objects that are partially visible or overlapping?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is only 1 restriction, your truth bboxes with **the same class_id** shouldn't be overlapped more than IoU > 45%, because Yolo uses nms_threshold = 0.45.

In general, you should mark your objects in such a way as you want to detect these objects.